# WiX: Is it possible to customize [ProductName] during installation?

Tags: wix, wix3.6

I'm searching for secret way how to customize [ProductName] property during the multiinstance installation process (after or during the InstanceTransform process?).

The problem is that when you try to uninstall an instance usually it become a problem to recognize what you need to uninstall: those "predefined" product names like "App Instance 1", "App Instance 2", etc does not help you. Should go to registries and refresh memory...

Comment: Do you have found a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

The [`Instance`](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/wix_xsd_instance.htm) element, which goes under [`InstanceTransforms`](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/wix_xsd_instancetransforms.htm) element and describes a particular instance, has an attribute `ProductName`. This basically where you can define the product name (I mean, the `ProductName` property) of each instance.

If you dive deeper in the multiple instance behavior, you might find [this post](http://ysdevlog.blogspot.com/2011/08/revisited-multiple-instance.html) interesting.